# updating Swing JTextField

Tags: java, swing, setter, jtextfield

I can't `.setText(...)` for a `JTextField` outside of the class that creates the gui. I'm very confused and I feel like there is something basic I am missing. I need some help here.

Here is what I am doing:

In a class (called `MainClass`) I create an instance of a class that creates my gui

```
TestText gui = new TestText();
```

with a constructor that sets the default settings (a `JTextField` and a button with a listener). Then I call the a setter that I wrote, where I pass it a string that is to set the text of the `JTextField`:

```
gui.setText("new");
```

But `"new"` doesn't show up on the gui.

I know my setter works from within the class because if I make a call to the setter from the button that I created in gui then the changes show up on the gui.

The part that really confuses me is this: If I call my getter just before my setter, then it returns the old value. Then if I call the getter again after I call the setter then it returns the new value, while the gui continues to show the old value. I thought that maybe it just isn't repainting the gui so I tried all kinds of permutations of `.invalidate()`, `.validate()`, `.update()` and `.repaint()`, all from the `MainClass` and from inside the setter. But none did anything.

Is it possible that I somehow have 2 different instances of the gui and I'm only editing one of them?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class TestText {
    private JTextField textField;
    private JButton button;
    private JPanel frame;
    JFrame jFrame;
    public void setText(String text) {
        textField.setText(text);
    }
    public String getText() {
        return textField.getText();
    }
    public TestText() {
        this.textField.setText("98.6");
        this.jFrame = new JFrame("TestText");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                setText("new (button)");
            }
        });
    }
    public void setData(TestText data) {
        data.setText("new (setData)");
    }
    public void getData(TestText data) {
    }
    public boolean isModified(TestText data) {
        return false;
    }
    public void createGui(String[] args) {
        jFrame.setContentPane(new TestText().frame);
        jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jFrame.pack();
        jFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

and then here's the main class that I'm trying to create the gui from:

```
public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        TestText gui = new TestText();
        gui.createGui(null);

        System.out.println(gui.getText());
        gui.setData(gui);
        System.out.println(gui.getText());
        gui.setText("new (MainClass)");
        System.out.println(gui.getText());
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)?

Comment: There is absolutely no need for invalidate(), validate(), update() or repaint(). All you need to do is invoke `setText()` on the text field. If you have a proper reference to the text field that is displayed on the GUI then the text field will automatically be repainted. Of course this assumes the code is executed on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT).

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're missing the reference to the text field I think...

```
gui.referenceToTextField.setText("new word");
```

**EDIT:** Very nice SSCCE! However, there are several problems (not in the order provided, necessarily).

1. You are overriding the `setText()` method. Don't do this unless you want the method to do something different—why you would want to do this I have no idea.
2. You aren't even using the `args` array in the `createGui()` method. You can create methods without specifying any parameters/arguments.
3. The `getData()` method is, right now, useless (If I were you, given what you're trying to accomplish, I would remove the method entirely). I'm assuming, from the apt method name (another good thing to do), that you want to retrieve the data from the text field. Put this line inside the method (and change the word `void` to `String`) and you should be set!

   ```
   return textField.getText();
   ```
4. Truthfully, this shouldn't even run due to a NullPointerException. You aren't initializing any of the components other than the JFrame. You need to do things like `textField = new JTextField(20)`.
5. Even if you could run this, the button wouldn't work at all because the button hasn't been told that it does anything. To do this call `button.addActionListener()` with the name of the listening class as the argument. If the GUI and listening classes happen to be in one class together (like I will show you in a minute), the argument is simply `this`.
6. You aren't adding any components to the frame. For every component you wish to put into your frame, you must call `add(Component cmpt)`.

---

Having said this, I think I'm just going to try to recreate what you're trying to do here into one class. You don't really need two separate classes unless the listening portion is excessively long.

---

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class TestText extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    JTextField textField = new JTextField(20);
    JButton set = new JButton("Set Text");
    JButton get = new JButton("Get Text");

    public TestText() {
        super();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        add(textField);
        set.addActionListener(this); //this tells the program that the button actually triggers an event
        add(set);
        get.addActionListener(this);
        add(get);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        if (event.getSource() == set) {
            textField.setText(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter a new word for the text field:"));
        } else {
            System.out.println(textField.getText());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestText tt = new TestText();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am missing the reference... I'll play around with that when I get home and if I can't get it working I'll post an SSCCE. Thanks.

Comment: @Bats If this solves your problem, please accept this answer as the correct one. :)

Comment: @Bats Could you put that into your question perhaps? It'll be more understandable to me (and others) that way. Thanks! :)

Comment: I found that the referenceToTextField appears to be correct within my setter. I updated the original post to include an SSCCE so you can see where I'm going wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Oops, I just realized that you found a solution. You can still accept this if you want. :P

Comment: @Bats To accept an answer, click the unfilled checkmark below the down arrow to the left of the answer you want to accept.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some reading I think it is due to my code not accessing the Event Dispatch Thread like @camickr suggested. [Here is some documentation](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Threads/swing/) that helped me solve my problem.